# checkValidity() causing error in IE9 and below

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

I'm using jQuery's `checkValidity()` in ajax form submissions and everything works fine until the form has a `select` element.

For example, I have a page that shows data based on the user's choice of row count. (Select how many rows of data) ... 10, 20, 30, etc. That's the only form on the page. They select, and all is fine in every browser except IE 9 and below.

Here's the line in the form submission script that's causing the error:

```
if (!$(this).get(0).checkValidity()) {return false;}
```

The error that is producing in IE is:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'checkValidity'

Anyone have an idea of how I can solve this? Works fine in every other browser.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation and http://html5please.com/#validation

Answer (score 7):

> I'm using jQuery's `checkValidity()`...

[`checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation_API) is not a jQuery method, but a native DOM API method. The code you quoted...

```
if (!$(this).get(0).checkValidity()) {return false;
```

...gets a reference to the native DOM element (and `$(this).get(0)` is redundant, it could be replaced simply with `this`) and then calls the `checkValidity()` method on it.

It fails in IE9 and below because they haven't implemented that method.

Comment: Speaking of redudant *faux paus*, I managed to `.has(this)...not(this)` [on the same explression](http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/Ss3xU/25/show/). I'm sure you have NO desire to see what that mongrel double tongue looks like and thus *refrain* from a peak at the code...